# How do I randomly select an object from an array multiple times and store each in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to pull an object out of an array of objects using a function that randomizes the object selected based on some rules I preset (each object has an upper and lower bound from 0 to 1 which controls its "chances" of being selected.

I want to run this function multiple times and store the result of each separate call in a new array.

Below is the code I wrote.  It generates the prescribed number of different objects, however the portion where I try to build the array of those is instead just pushing multiple of the same call into the array so I end up with an array full of the same object I randomly pulled.

```
const animals = [
  {
    upperProb: 1,
    lowerProb: 0.8,
    Animal: 'Zebra'
  },
  {
    upperProb: 0.8,
    lowerProb: 0.25,
    Animal: 'Cat'
  },
  {
    upperProb: 0.25,
    lowerProb: 0,
    Animal: 'Narwhal'
  },
];

const generatedAnimal = {};

let animalChoice = () => {
  const numGen = Math.random();
  console.log(numGen);

  const selectedAnimal = animals.find(animal =>
    animal.upperProb > numGen
    && animal.lowerProb <= numGen
  );

  generatedAnimal.Animal = selectedAnimal.Animal;

  return generatedAnimal;

};

console.log(generatedAnimal);

const generateDist = () => {
  let animalDist = [];
  let i = 0;
  do {
    animalChoice();
    animalDist.push(generatedAnimal);
    console.log(generatedAnimal);
    i++
  } while (i < 10)
  console.log(animalDist);
}

generateDist();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is almost correct.  You are pushing the same reference to your array multiple times and thus getting the **ref 2** output. You are also making generatedAnimal a constant when it should be a variable. Easy to fix, see code below:

```js
const animals = [
  {
    upperProb: 1,
    lowerProb: 0.8,
    Animal: 'Zebra'
  },
  {
    upperProb: 0.8,
    lowerProb: 0.25,
    Animal: 'Cat'
  },
  {
    upperProb: 0.25,
    lowerProb: 0,
    Animal: 'Narwhal'
  },
];

/*********change this**********************
const generatedAnimal = {};
**************to***************************/
var generatedAnimal = {};
   
let animalChoice = () => {
  const numGen = Math.random();
  //console.log(numGen);
   


  const selectedAnimal = animals.find(animal =>
    animal.upperProb > numGen
    && animal.lowerProb <= numGen
  );

  generatedAnimal.Animal = selectedAnimal.Animal;

  return generatedAnimal;

};

//console.log(generatedAnimal);

const generateDist = () => {
  let animalDist = [];
  let i = 0;
  do {

  /**********add this************/
    generatedAnimal={};
  /******************************/
    animalChoice();
    animalDist.push(generatedAnimal);
    //console.log(generatedAnimal);
    i++
  } while (i < 10)
  console.log(animalDist);
}

generateDist();
```

Comment: This works great, thanks for the help with both the solution and information regarding the variable change.  I had it in my head that objects are best declared as constants but now looking back I may have just made that up in my head (not totally uncommon for me).  I do have one question, why are we setting generatedAnimal to be a new object inside generateDist?

Comment: you defined your function animalChoice as a let which has a scope of block. var generatedAnimal is defined outside a function so has global scope. You need to create a new object before you call animalChoice.  There are cleaner implementations but this makes the fewest changes to your code.

Comment: take another look at the snippet.  I updated it. We first define generatedAnimal as global, and then inside the function we first set it to {}.  This seems more intuitive to me but either way will work